# from var_dump to variable

Tags: php, var-dump

This is how looks my var_dump variable.

```
object(stdClass)#879 (3) {
      ["row"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["option_id"]=>
        string(2) "20"
      }
      ["rows"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          ["option_id"]=>
          string(2) "20"
        }
      }
      ["num_rows"]=>
      int(1)
    }
```

I need to get option_id in this case option_id = 20
e.g. `$option_id = 20`

When I try this `$variable['row']['option_id']` I get null value.

Comment: `$variable->row->option_id`

Comment: I try this, but now I get blank field.

Comment: Does this work?
$variable->row['option_id'];

Comment: What do you see when you do var_dump($variable->row);

Comment: Now I going right way, with var_dump($variable->row['option_id']) I get string(2) "20"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable is an object of `stdClass`, so you have to access the properties instead of an index. For example:

`$variable->num_rows`

If you want to get the `option_id`, you have to use this (combine object and array syntax):

`$option_id = $variable->row["option_id"];`